# Adjust header and footer width

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, geometry

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside=true,11pt,openright]{book}

% packages:
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparsep}
    \addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparwidth}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}
    \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}



\begin{document}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Here's what the document looks like, the header (and footer) goes outside the page. I would like both of them to extend slightly beyond the text width.
[image]

Comment: Loading package `geometry` changes the page layout and enlarges `marginparwidth`. You can remove the package or load it with option `pass` (disables all of the geometry options and calculations except `verbose` and `showframe`) or you adjust `marginparwidth` to ensure that the marginpar does not go outside of the paper: eg.`\usepackage[marginparwidth=2cm]{geometry}`.

Comment: `fancyhdr` is not the only way to customise headers and footers: `titleps`, which is a companion package of `titlesec`, has a `widenhead(*)` command.

Comment: @esdd Thanks your last suggestion with 1cm instead of 2cm did the exact job I wanted!

Comment: For completeness: The `fancyhdr` way to enlarge the header/footer width would be `\fancyhfoffset[LE,RO]{1cm}`. It extends to the left on even and to the right on odd pages. See the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two little changes to your MWE and you are done:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside=true,11pt,openright]{book}

% packages:
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{.5cm}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{.5cm}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}



\begin{document}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could reduce the 2 lines `\addtolength{\headwidth}{.5cm}` to one line `\addtolength{\headwidth}{1cm}`.

Comment: @desteritas Yes commment the first line (%) and change 0.5cm in 1cm in the second one. You will have 1 cm more heather on even pages and 1 cm more heather on odd pages.

Comment: Yes you can have this:
%\addtolength{\headwidth}{.5cm}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{1cm}