# Increase header/footer margin with scrlayer-scrpage

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrbook

I want to edit header/footer of my document with the scrlayer-scrpage package. Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[english,BCOR=6mm,cdgeometry=twoside,DIV=12,open=right,headsepline]{tudscrbook}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{isodate}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

I want header and footer to extend slightly beyond the text width. A similar question was asked yesterday ([Adjust header and footer width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/620317/adjust-header-and-footer-width/620356#620356)) but there fancyhdr package is used which is not compatible with scrbook.

**Edit**: Also, I want to know how to format the chapter titles to look like:
[image]

Comment: Please do not raise several issues in one question. Ask a separate question for the chapter title formatting (after searching for an existing solution on the site).

Answer (score 1):

You can use option `headwidth=\textwidth+1cm:0pt`. The syntax is `headwidth=<width>:<offset>:<offset>`, see also the KOMA-Script. If there is only one `<offset>` given (like in the example), this offset is used on both even and odd pages.

To get a prefix line for the chapters add class option `chapterprefixline`. This works for both classes `scrbook` and `tudscrbook`.

Example with `scrbook`:

```latex
\documentclass[english,BCOR=6mm,DIV=12,headsepline,
  chapterprefix% <- added: prefix line for chapters
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{isodate}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\KOMAoptions{headwidth=\textwidth+1cm:0pt}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Example with class `tudscrbooks` (uses package `geometry` and loads package `scrlayer-scrpage`):

```latex
\documentclass[english,BCOR=6mm,cdgeometry=twoside,
  %DIV=12,% page layout is calculated by package geometry
  open=right,headsepline,
  chapterprefix% <- added: prefix line for chapters
]{tudscrbook}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{isodate}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\AtBeginDocument{\KOMAoptions{headwidth=\textwidth+1cm:0pt}}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello. This is not working as intended. I would like the header and footer to extend slightly beyond the text width on the left side on even pages and on the right side on odd pages.  Right now, it extends on both sides on even pages and only on the right side on odd pages.

Comment: Also, when I compile your code, "Chapter 1" and "Heading on.." is displayed in the same line.

Comment: @modeltheory Did you really run *my* code? Note the offset of `0pt` in `headwidth=\textwidth+1cm:0pt`. To get the extra line with »Chapter 1« you have to add option `chapterprefix` to the class options. This works for both `scrbook` and `tudscrbook`.

Comment: Yes, I had. Your previous edit has '0cm' instead of '0pt'. I have added the 'chapterprefix' in the class options but I get "Chapter 1Heading on.." as the title instead of "Chapter 1\\ Heading...".

Comment: `0pt` = `0cm` ;-) I have tested my examples using MiKTeX, TeXLive 2018, 2019, 2020 and 2021. The result is shown in the screen shots. Maybe there are additional code in your example overwritting the settings.