How can I have this type of style? (Bottom extended from main text, and a sidebar on left)

I want to have this kind of styling in which bottom extends from the main text, and there is a sidebar.

You could start with https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/620317/277964 (and several more similar questions) and if you fail to get the desired result, show what you've tried. The minimal working example should also eliminate other ambiguities, such as which class is used, whether the document is single-sided (as I assume) or double-sided, should left-hand or right-hand pages handled different (and how), etc.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
